# Redirect output of one exe to another exe : C#

Tags: c#, redirect

I have created two simple .exe files. One of them takes a filename parameter at runtime and reads the contents of the file to the console. The other waits on its console's input and then reads it; for now it just has to print out to the console, but eventually I'll have to redirect the read in text to a new txt file. My question is, how can I redirect the output of the first exe to the 2nd exe's console where it can be read in?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide! :)

-Chris

Comment: I hope this is the only way to achieve that ,because if you designed this by you're self which handles 2 .NET Assemblies Stream Redirect using Process is the worst Design Ever seen .You could use Named Pipe's , Sockets ,WCF ,Web Service or even a DataBase(Hope not).

Comment: @Cody: Worst design ever seen? Have you tried telling that to nix users? It's a common design pattern in their world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably do something with the command line using the pipe redirect operator:

```
ConsoleApp1.exe | ConsoleApp2.exe
```

The pipe operator redirects the console output from the first app to the standard input of the second app. You can find more info [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) (the link is for XP but the rules apply to Windows Vista and Windows 7 as well).

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx)

```
// Start the child process.
 Process p = new Process();
 // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
 p.Start();
 // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
 // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
 // p.WaitForExit();
 // Read the output stream first and then wait.
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

you could get a line by line read instead by:

```
///...
string output;
while( ( output = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine() ) != null )
{
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
p.WaitForExit();
```